# Naive Bayesian Algorithm in Python with cross-validation

Tags: python, machine-learning

I've wrote this code to evaluate a Machine Learning - the classification problem for digits recognition as in the figure below:

[image]

For more details and to check the whole code, check the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/MeqdadDarweesh/Numbers-Recognition-by-Naive-Bayes-classifier).

Its important to notice that these numbers are in old Indian form, currently they are called Arabic numbers.

This is used to test the number 4 only:

```
### Naive Bayes Classifier ###
## Done by: Meqdad Darweesh ##

### Importing statements ###
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as mvn
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

### Training data ###

# First class
c4 = np.array([ [8,11,12,12,13,16,20,20,22,23,22,20,19,18,16,16,15,12,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,3,2],
    [3,10,18,20,21,23,24,21,21,22,21,20,18,16,15,14,12,12,6,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,1],
[2,7,8,11,19,20,22,22,23,22,22,23,22,20,18,18,20,20,18,16,14,11,11,11,9,8,4,4,4,3],
[3,12,14,19,22,23,26,23,21,21,19,18,18,17,16,15,15,13,9,9,9,8,8,5,5,4,4,4,3,1],
[3,6,8,15,18,21,24,26,25,24,24,23,21,21,20,17,17,16,16,14,11,11,11,11,9,8,8,8,5,1],
[4,8,15,19,24,25,25,26,27,25,22,21,20,19,19,17,14,11,12,13,13,13,13,13,12,10,10,9,4,3],
[5,12,15,22,22,25,25,24,21,19,19,19,18,18,18,17,14,15,13,9,9,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,1],
[4,9,9,9,10,17,18,18,19,21,22,20,20,16,17,16,14,12,11,8,7,7,7,7,5,4,3,3,3,1],
[0,7,8,9,16,20,20,21,21,22,23,23,23,20,19,17,16,16,13,10,9,8,8,8,7,4,4,4,3,1],
[2,7,8,9,11,11,12,17,21,22,22,21,19,19,17,16,14,11,8,8,8,8,7,4,4,4,4,4,4,2],
[7,16,19,23,24,24,21,19,18,17,16,14,14,12,11,8,8,8,7,7,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,2],
[4,11,15,18,21,22,22,22,21,20,18,16,15,14,12,7,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,2],
[1,6,14,17,22,23,24,27,27,27,23,20,20,18,17,17,15,15,10,10,9,8,7,5,4,4,3,3,3,2],
[5,9,11,16,22,22,23,24,23,22,16,15,10,10,11,11,10,10,9,5,4,4,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,2],
[2,7,9,21,22,24,26,26,26,22,20,18,18,16,15,14,12,8,8,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,2,1],
[0,10,13,16,19,21,25,26,24,22,19,17,17,15,15,13,11,7,6,6,5,3,4,4,4,3,3,3,2,1],
[3,5,5,12,15,19,21,23,24,24,24,23,20,18,17,17,15,13,10,9,8,8,7,7,7,7,6,2,2,1],
[5,7,15,18,18,20,21,20,19,18,17,17,17,16,15,15,15,13,12,12,11,9,9,4,3,3,3,3,3,3],
[4,14,18,21,24,23,22,22,20,18,16,14,12,10,6,6,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,1],
[5,7,9,14,18,18,22,22,22,20,18,17,15,13,12,10,7,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
[5,7,8,13,17,19,19,21,21,22,20,17,15,14,13,10,7,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3],
[5,8,9,16,19,19,20,23,21,18,18,12,11,10,8,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1],
[3,15,18,20,23,23,20,22,19,14,14,14,13,11,8,5,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,1],
[6,13,17,20,20,21,22,20,20,18,19,19,16,16,14,14,14,11,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,1],
[5,8,8,18,19,20,20,21,22,19,17,15,14,13,10,8,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3],
[5,9,10,12,9,8,7,7,15,18,20,20,17,12,11,9,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2],
[5,6,13,17,19,22,21,21,22,21,20,18,18,17,14,8,8,8,9,9,7,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3],
[4,10,12,16,20,21,21,19,18,17,18,18,17,16,15,14,12,11,10,6,6,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
[5,10,14,18,22,19,21,18,18,19,19,18,15,15,12,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1],
[6,9,11,12,10,10,13,16,18,21,20,19,8,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3],
[4,8,12,17,18,21,21,21,17,16,15,13,7,8,8,7,7,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,4,4,3,3,3,2],
[3,7,12,17,19,20,22,20,20,19,19,18,17,16,16,15,14,13,12,9,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,1],
[2,5,8,10,10,11,11,10,13,17,19,20,22,22,20,16,15,15,13,11,8,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,1],
[4,8,10,11,10,15,15,17,18,19,18,20,18,17,15,13,12,7,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,2],
[2,8,12,15,18,20,19,20,21,21,23,19,19,16,16,16,14,12,10,7,7,7,7,6,3,3,3,3,2,1],
[2,13,17,18,21,22,20,18,18,17,17,15,13,11,8,8,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,1],
[6,6,9,14,15,18,20,20,22,20,16,16,15,11,8,8,8,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,4],
[8,13,16,20,20,20,19,17,17,17,17,15,14,13,10,6,3,3,3,4,4,4,3,3,4,3,3,3,2,2],
[5,9,17,18,19,18,17,16,14,13,12,12,11,10,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,3,3,3,3],
[4,6,8,11,16,17,18,20,16,17,16,17,17,16,14,12,12,10,9,9,8,8,6,4,3,3,3,2,2,2] ])

# Second class
c7 = np.array([ [5,7,7,8,8,9,9,9,8,8,7,8,8,8,9,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,11,12,16,25,29,29,11],
[6,6,6,7,6,6,5,6,6,6,5,6,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,8,8,11,17,26,27,27,19],
[3,7,7,7,7,6,7,7,7,7,8,7,8,8,9,9,9,10,9,8,8,8,9,9,12,16,24,28,28,6],
[3,7,7,8,9,9,9,8,9,8,8,8,7,7,8,7,7,7,7,8,9,8,10,11,14,20,26,26,15,3],
[5,6,7,8,7,8,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,7,7,6,6,7,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,25,27,30,21],
[2,7,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,10,9,8,9,8,7,8,9,11,10,10,13,15,17,14,16,14,13,12,4],
[6,7,7,7,7,7,9,9,8,8,6,6,5,6,6,8,8,8,10,9,9,9,9,11,16,21,22,18,14,10],
[4,6,6,6,5,6,6,6,8,7,7,7,8,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,10,16,17,15,14,10,8,7,4],
[5,8,9,9,7,6,7,6,7,6,7,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,7,8,8,7,9,9,9,24,30,30,30,15],
[7,8,9,5,6,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,12,24,30,30,20],
[4,5,5,5,6,5,6,6,6,6,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,6,6,6,8,7,7,9,16,23,26,19,9,5],
[1,7,8,8,7,6,7,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,8,9,11,14,17,17,18,14,8],
[7,8,8,8,7,7,5,6,5,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,17,26,29,24,17,13],
[2,3,8,8,7,7,7,6,6,7,7,6,7,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,8,10,10,21,28,30,30,30,8,1],
[8,9,9,9,7,7,8,7,8,8,9,9,8,8,7,9,9,9,8,8,9,10,11,14,17,20,14,12,9,1],
[4,7,7,7,7,9,8,9,9,9,8,9,9,10,9,11,9,10,10,11,11,11,15,15,11,12,15,13,13,6],
[5,5,6,7,7,6,6,7,8,9,10,11,11,11,11,10,9,10,11,12,12,14,15,15,14,13,13,11,8,5],
[6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,12,13,14,15,15,15,17,20,20,18,16,13,9,7,5,3],
[1,6,6,6,7,9,9,8,8,7,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,8,9,8,8,8,8,9,27,30,30,30,4],
[2,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,7,7,7,7,8,8,7,8,9,28,28,30,30,29,5],
[4,7,7,6,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6,5,6,6,7,6,8,9,9,9,9,10,12,15,16,17,15,8,8],
[5,6,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,9,9,8,8,8,8,6,7,6,7,6,8,7,7,10,16,19,14,14,10,6],
[5,5,7,8,9,8,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,9,8,8,9,9,12,14,16,13,14,15,12,10],
[5,5,6,7,6,6,5,5,6,7,8,8,10,12,11,12,11,11,11,11,12,15,15,14,11,10,10,9,7,5],
[1,6,7,8,9,8,8,7,9,9,9,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,11,11,14,16,21,21,18,16,13,3],
[2,6,7,7,6,6,5,6,7,7,8,9,9,9,10,10,10,9,9,9,9,9,10,14,13,14,13,13,10,5],
[6,7,7,7,8,7,7,7,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,7,8,9,10,12,16,18,17,13,13,10,8,6],
[6,6,7,7,8,7,7,7,7,8,8,9,9,9,9,11,11,10,10,11,13,11,9,10,11,12,12,11,9,6],
[4,7,8,8,9,10,10,8,7,8,7,8,9,8,10,10,9,11,10,9,8,10,12,23,20,17,13,12,11,5],
[1,7,8,8,8,8,7,7,8,8,8,9,10,10,11,12,13,12,12,13,14,11,10,10,11,11,11,8,7,3],
[5,6,7,8,9,9,7,8,7,8,8,7,8,7,8,8,11,11,11,11,12,15,14,11,11,11,11,10,8,6],
[5,6,8,8,9,9,8,7,7,7,7,8,8,10,9,9,11,12,11,11,12,13,10,8,7,9,9,9,9,3],
[7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,8,8,10,13,15,20,18,19,14,9,5],
[2,6,6,7,6,6,6,6,6,7,6,6,7,7,7,8,7,8,8,9,11,12,12,15,18,20,17,16,12,1],
[5,7,7,8,7,7,7,7,7,6,7,7,8,7,7,8,8,9,9,8,9,8,9,10,17,18,22,19,13,8],
[2,4,6,6,6,6,5,6,7,8,8,8,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,13,17,20,23,26,24,15,13,3,2],
[2,4,6,8,8,9,10,11,8,9,7,8,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,10,12,16,20,23,27,28,23,9,6],
[2,5,5,5,6,7,9,10,10,9,8,8,7,8,8,7,7,8,8,9,9,11,11,12,19,25,25,20,16,1],
[5,7,8,8,8,8,9,8,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,10,9,11,11,11,14,16,21,24,27,21,16,9,4],
[3,6,7,8,9,8,7,8,8,7,8,7,7,6,8,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,9,23,29,30,29,26,8,2] ])

# Third class
c9 = np.array([[4,7,9,11,12,13,12,10,9,10,9,9,10,10,9,9,12,15,16,18,20,21,23,27,22,18,10,9,6,3],
[7,8,10,11,10,11,13,10,11,10,10,10,10,9,9,10,13,13,13,15,16,20,20,17,16,14,13,13,7,3],
[7,9,10,10,9,7,8,7,8,10,10,11,12,12,13,14,16,15,12,9,9,9,8,9,5,5,5,4,4,3],
[5,10,11,12,12,10,10,9,9,9,8,9,9,13,13,14,15,15,15,15,16,16,15,11,10,9,7,6,5,4],
[6,8,11,11,13,9,10,9,9,8,7,7,8,8,12,16,16,14,10,10,9,8,8,7,8,7,7,7,6,5],
[9,12,14,16,11,9,8,10,9,8,8,8,9,8,8,8,12,13,14,13,13,13,11,11,9,8,8,8,7,5],
[7,9,11,12,13,9,7,9,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,17,16,15,15,13,13,11,13,12,12,13,12,10,8,7],
[6,8,9,11,10,10,9,8,9,8,8,9,9,9,10,8,8,11,16,17,17,15,14,11,8,10,9,8,7,6],
[8,10,12,12,11,10,10,10,9,10,10,8,8,9,14,14,14,14,17,19,17,11,9,8,7,6,7,6,5,3],
[8,12,14,16,16,12,11,10,9,9,9,9,9,14,17,17,16,15,15,15,10,9,6,6,6,6,7,7,6,5],
[7,10,12,13,11,11,9,9,9,8,8,9,9,9,12,11,12,10,11,12,12,11,12,9,7,6,6,6,4,3],
[8,11,14,16,13,10,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,14,16,14,12,9,8,8,9,9,9,8,8,8,8,8,7,6],
[5,7,11,12,11,10,9,9,8,9,8,8,9,10,10,13,14,11,9,10,11,9,8,7,8,7,7,6,5,4],
[3,9,10,12,13,12,11,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,12,14,13,13,14,15,14,12,11,11,9,7,6,5,2],
[6,9,11,14,15,14,11,11,9,8,9,10,15,16,15,11,12,11,12,11,12,9,8,6,5,5,5,5,4,4],
[3,8,10,10,12,11,11,9,9,9,9,7,7,8,8,9,10,11,14,14,15,15,14,14,12,14,10,9,8,5],
[7,10,11,14,15,11,11,10,10,10,9,10,11,13,15,13,12,12,12,13,10,10,8,8,6,7,7,6,5,3],
[5,8,9,10,13,11,9,9,8,8,8,8,7,8,9,11,13,14,16,14,13,12,17,17,17,16,12,8,7,3],
[9,9,13,15,10,9,8,7,7,7,6,6,8,14,15,17,16,12,10,10,11,11,9,7,7,7,7,7,6,5],
[5,9,12,13,14,11,10,9,8,8,9,9,11,13,16,15,14,14,15,14,14,14,8,7,7,6,5,4,3,0],
[7,10,11,14,14,11,10,11,9,8,9,9,10,11,14,15,14,13,12,13,14,16,19,18,15,14,12,9,7,3],
[6,8,8,11,11,10,9,10,8,9,9,8,9,10,11,13,13,12,12,13,12,11,11,10,10,9,9,7,6,5],
[4,8,9,12,13,13,12,12,10,11,10,10,11,11,10,11,15,16,15,17,17,18,13,12,10,9,9,8,7,4],
[7,9,9,12,12,13,10,10,10,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,14,14,12,10,10,11,13,12,13,16,15,12,10,8],
[7,10,11,12,14,11,11,10,10,10,10,10,10,14,15,15,14,12,11,11,13,14,13,12,10,10,9,8,6,4],
[7,9,12,12,13,13,11,11,11,8,9,10,8,8,8,14,14,17,17,18,19,21,19,14,13,13,11,8,5,3],
[5,10,11,12,12,13,12,11,12,11,11,11,11,10,10,13,13,15,15,15,17,14,13,12,12,13,12,10,8,5],
[8,9,12,13,11,10,9,10,9,9,9,9,9,11,12,14,13,13,11,10,9,8,7,8,7,7,7,6,4,3],
[5,9,10,12,13,11,11,10,11,10,9,8,7,8,8,13,14,13,13,12,12,12,11,9,9,9,9,9,7,4],
[8,9,13,14,13,11,11,9,8,9,9,9,9,9,14,15,13,12,11,11,11,9,9,7,8,8,8,7,5,4],
[6,7,10,13,14,15,13,12,11,11,11,10,9,10,11,15,13,12,11,12,13,12,12,11,8,7,6,5,5,4],
[5,9,10,11,12,13,11,9,9,10,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,13,15,14,17,18,19,19,16,15,10,7,6,3],
[8,8,10,12,13,12,11,11,10,10,9,8,9,11,12,13,12,10,10,11,9,10,10,11,11,11,8,6,5,4],
[7,9,10,11,13,14,14,12,11,11,11,12,13,16,16,16,15,15,14,14,15,14,13,11,10,9,7,6,4,3],
[3,7,10,12,13,13,13,11,11,10,10,10,11,11,13,15,16,16,15,15,14,17,16,17,18,16,14,12,8,5],
[6,8,9,11,12,12,10,11,11,10,9,9,9,8,9,11,16,15,15,13,13,13,13,12,13,12,11,8,6,4],
[5,7,9,12,12,13,12,10,10,9,11,11,9,10,9,11,12,13,14,13,13,13,17,18,21,19,15,10,8,5],
[4,7,8,10,11,12,12,14,11,11,11,11,11,12,10,11,15,16,19,26,28,28,28,28,27,22,20,16,4,4],
[4,7,10,11,12,12,13,11,11,10,10,10,10,11,11,10,10,12,16,17,20,21,22,18,16,13,9,7,5,2],
[1,5,11,12,14,15,15,12,11,9,9,9,8,10,10,11,14,15,17,16,17,18,19,16,15,13,10,9,5,4] ])


### 4-fold cross-validation ###


kf = KFold(n_splits=4)

i4 = 0
i7 = 0
i9 = 0

c4_error = 0
c7_error = 0
c9_error = 0
final_accuracy = 0

print("\n")

print("...::: Class 4 cross-validation :::...")

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(c4):
    i4+=1
    print("\n")
    print("The iteration #", i4)

    X_train4, X_test4 = c4[train_index], c4[test_index]
    X_train7, X_test7 = c7[train_index], c7[test_index]
    X_train9, X_test9 = c9[train_index], c9[test_index]

    X_train4_mean = np.mean(X_train4, axis=0)
    X_train7_mean = np.mean(X_train7, axis=0)
    X_train9_mean = np.mean(X_train9, axis=0)

    v4 = mvn(X_train4_mean, cov = np.cov(X_train4.T) + np.eye(30))
    v7 = mvn(X_train7_mean, cov = np.cov(X_train7.T) + np.eye(30))
    v9 = mvn(X_train9_mean, cov = np.cov(X_train9.T) + np.eye(30))

    res4 = v4.pdf(X_test4)
    res7 = v7.pdf(X_test4)
    res9 = v9.pdf(X_test4)

    print("\n")

    print("In 4 - res4: ", res4)
    print("In 4 - res7: ", res7)
    print("In 4 - res9: ", res9)

    for x in range(0, 10):
        if res4[x] > res7[x]:
            if res4[x] > res9[x]:
                print("Sample",x, "is belongs to class 4")
        elif res7[x] > res4[x]:
            if res7[x] > res9[x]:
                c4_error +=1
                print("Sample",x, "is belongs to class 7, Error")
        elif res9[x] > res4[x]:
            if res9[x] > res7[x]:
                c4_error += 1
                print("Sample",x, "is belongs to class 9, Error")
    print("\n")

if c4_error == 0:
    print("Average accuracy C4: 100% ")
else:
    print("Average accuracy C4: %", (c4_error / 10) * 100)

print("\n")
### The End ###
```

Comment: "digits recognition as in the figure below" I see a mirrored 3, something resembling a 9 and I don't have a clue what character is in the middle. Looks mostly like a `V` I suppose. Where did the values in your numpy arrays (you call them a class, they're not a class) come from? What's your current average accuracy on the data set you used? Is the data set available somewhere?

Comment: Long story short: we can see what you did. Can you explain why you did what you did? There are quite a lot of numbers in your code I can't place.

Comment: @Mast Maybe they're [Eastern Arabic numerals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals)?

Comment: These numbers are in old indian form, currently they are called arabic numbers, here is this link [https://ibb.co/j056ES] you can see the equivalent value for each number.
the arrays [called class in M.L. not from programming point of view] represent a statistical data for the numbers from a predefined database for the numbers.

Comment: You can see some details on the repository link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

There is a whole lot of repetition in this code. Especially if you look at the complete code for the 3 classes. Imagine you need to add a fourth class...

The way to tackle this is to separate the program in logical chunks. Each performing a part, and glueing those together.

An item in this is to return something useful instead of printing an intermediate result. If you need the intermediate results in the text, I suggest to look at the `logging` builtin module

## Code

Let's work step by step.

### sample definition

Instead of hardcoding different variable for the different digits, I would use a dict:

```
samples = {
    '4': c4,
    '7': c7,
    '9': c9,
}
```

### split the samples

... along the train- and testindex:

```
def split_sample(samples, train_index, test_index):
    for sample_name, sample in samples.items():
        yield sample_name, (sample[train_index], sample[test_index])
```

... splits the sample in training and test data.

### make the distribution:

uses the training data to generate the mvn:

```
def make_distribution(x_train):
    x_train_mean = np.mean(x_train, axis=0)
    covariance = np.cov(x_train.T) + np.eye(30)
    return mvn(x_train_mean, cov=covariance)
```

### make the pdfs

```
def make_pdf(samples, sample_name):
    kf = KFold(n_splits=4)
    split = kf.split(samples[sample_name])
    for iteration, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(split, 1):
        samples_splits = dict(split_sample(samples, train_index, test_index))
        distributions = (
            (sample_name, make_distribution(x_train)) 
            for sample_name, (x_train, x_test) in samples_splits.items()
            )
        x_test = samples_splits[sample_name][1]
        yield iteration, {
            sample_name: distribution.pdf(x_test)
            for sample_name, distribution in distributions
        }
```

### find which class

Here your code contains a magic number `10`. I assume the 10 is the length of the testdata. Try to avoid magic numbers like that as much as possible. Here you can solve it by using `zip`.

Instead of for `x in range(0, 10):`, it is better to use `enumerate`:

```
def find_class(pdfs):
    fits = zip(*([(x, name) for x in pdf] for name, pdf in pdfs.items()))
    for x, fit in enumerate(fits):
        order = [name for _, name in sorted(fit, reverse=True)]
        yield x, order
```

This method sorts the different pdfs at the different x-points from high to low. In case of an ex aequo, it sorts alphabetically. This is easier than using the nested `if`s.

Instead of dividing it manually by 10, use `sum` and `len`.

### gluing it together:

To calculate the accuracy, instead of dividing it manually by 10, use `sum` and `len`:

```
for sample_name in samples.keys():
    for iteration, pdfs in make_pdf(samples, sample_name):
        classes = dict(find_class(pdfs))
#         print(classes)
        matches = [order[0] == sample_name for order in classes.values()]
#         print(matches)
        accuracy = sum(matches) / len(classes)
        print(f'accuracy for `{sample_name}` in iteration {iteration}: {accuracy}')
```

## Testing

By doing it like this, you can test each part of the code individually.

## main guard

It is best to put all of the script-specific code (not the functions, but the definition of samples for example) behind a `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard, so you can import this later in another script or program.